# Python package in ubuntu

Tags: apt, python

My current python version is python 2.7 (`python --version`), However, I've accidentally removed `python2.7` from `/usr/lib/` so I cannot do anything and I see this error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does `sudo apt install --reinstall python2.7` helps?

Comment: If mook765's idea doesn't work and all you did was just delete the file (i.e., not completely remove the package), you can try to use an Ubuntu boot disk to get the executable and copy it back...  If you use the same Ubuntu version, the executables should be similar.  Alternatively, you can download the package manually from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python2.7) and extract the file(s) you need.

Comment: What @Ray says. Try @mook765's idea first; if that doesn't work, carefully note your `python` package version, then download and extract the missing files. Then reinstall python2.7, just to be sure.